# Priorities of multiple constraints on a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

In the following example, I have two constraints, `Foobar` and `IFoobar<T>`, on type T in generic class `FoobarList<T>`. But the compiler gives an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Foobar' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
interface IFoobar<T>
{
    T CreateFoobar();
}

class Foobar : IFoobar<Foobar>
{
    //some foobar stuffs
    public Foobar CreateFoobar() { return new Foobar(); }
}

class FoobarList<T> where T : Foobar, IFoobar<T>
{
    void Test(T rFoobar)
    {
        T foobar = rFoobar.CreateFoobar(); //error: cannot convert Foobar to T
    }
}
```

It seems the compiler considers CreateFoobar as a method in Foobar, but not the one in IFoobar. I can fix the compile by dividing Foobar into a base class FoobarBase, and implementing the interface IFoobar in its derived class, as follows:

```
interface IFoobar<T>
{
    T CreateFoobar();
}

abstract class FoobarBase
{
    //some foobar stuffs
}

class Foobar : FoobarBase, IFoobar<Foobar>
{
    public Foobar CreateFoobar() { return new Foobar(); }
}

class FoobarList<T> where T : FoobarBase, IFoobar<T>
{
    void Test(T rFoobar)
    {
        T foobar = rFoobar.CreateFoobar();
    }
}
```

It is cumbersome to divide Foobar into two classes. Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Does implementing the interface explicitly help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast `rFoobar` to `IFoobar<T>`:

```
T foobar = ((IFoobar<T>)rFoobar).CreateFoobar();
```

That way you're calling a method that returns `T` rather than just `Foobar`.

As Rotem suggests, changing the method in `Foobar` to use explicit interface implementation works too:

```
Foobar IFoobar<Foobar>.CreateFoobar() { return new Foobar(); }
```

That way that method won't be found in `T`, so again it will resolve to the interface method.